# Transliteración de la Amidá en Español - Transliteration of the Amidah into Spanish

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, shemoneh-esrei, shabbat-songs, transliteration

Estoy buscando una transliteración del rezo Shemoné-Esré en la lengua español. ¿Puede usted, por favor, ayudarme? Yo también quiero los rezos y cánticos para el Shabat.

I'm looking for a transliteration of the Shemone Esre into Spanish.  Can you please help me?  I also want the prayers and songs (Zemirot) for Shabbat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's nusach Sefard (or maybe Sephardi?): http://atase-bilbao.blogspot.com/2009/05/amida.html

And here's a harder-to-read version with both nusach sephard and Sephardi nusach: http://shalomhaverim.org/conversion10.html

For Kabalat Shabbat prayers, check out a this Spanish siddur with translation and transliteration: http://www.scribd.com/doc/82745593/Siddur-Beit-Hillel-El-Salvador.  It has commentary and "alternative versions" from the Reform siddur, Mishkan Tefilah, in it, and it's missing a lot.